# Strange ratio in speedup between release and debug builds in game "Life"

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote classic game "Life" with 4-sided neighbors. When I run it in **debug**, it says:

- Consecutive version: 4.2s
- Parallel version: 1.5s

Okey, it's good. But if I run it in **release**, it says:

- Consecutive version: 0.46s
- Parallel version: **1.23s**

Why? I run it on the computer with 4 kernels. I run 4 threads in parallel section. Answer is correct. But somethere is leak and I don't know that place. Can anybody help me?

---

I try to run it in Visual Studio 2008 and 2012. The results are same. OMP is enabled in the project settings.

To repeat my problem, you can find defined constant `PARALLEL` and set it to 1 or 0 to enable and disable OMP correspondingly. Answer will be in the `out.txt` ([out.txt](http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/45378834/file.html) - right answer example). The input must be in in.txt (my input - [in.txt](http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/26292950/file.html)). There are some russian symbols, you don't need to understand them, but the first number in `in.txt` means number of threads to run in parallel section (it's `4` in the example).

The main part is placed in the `StartSimulation` function. If you run the program, you will see some russian text with running time in the console.

The program code is big enough, so I add it with file hosting - [main.cpp](http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/73936376/file.html) (l2 means "lab 2" for me)

Some comments about `StartSimulation` function. I cuts 2D surface with cells into small rectangles. It is done by `AdjustKernelsParameters` function.

Comment: Please, do not put source files on file hosting services. Instead use a dedicated service like [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) which also provides syntax colouring for many languages and file formats.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev, I will take it into account in the future.
The final version with reduction : http://pastebin.com/8LXNqLYT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not find the ratio so strange. Having multiple threads co-operate is a complex business and has overheads.

Access to shared memory needs to be serialized which normally involves some form of locking mechanism and contention between threads where they have to wait for the lock to be released.
Such shared variables need to be synchronized between the processor cores which can give significant slowdowns. Also the compiler needs to treat these critical areas differently as a "sequence point".

All this reduces the scope for per thread optimization both in the processor hardware and the compiler for each thread when it is working with the shared variable.

It seems that in this case the overheads of parallelization outweigh the optimization possibilities for the single threaded case.

If there were more work for each thread to do independently before needed to access a shared variable then these overheads would be less significant.

Comment: You're right. I added `reduction( + : livingCount)` with `livingCount` instead of atomic `#omp critical`. A speedup is about ~3.8 now. Thank you very much, I have tortured by this problem for 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `guided` loop schedule. This is a very bad choice given that you are dealing with a regular problem where each task can easily do exactly the same amount of work as any other if the domain is simply divided into chunks of equal size.

Replace `schedule(guided)` with `schedule(static)`. Also employ sum reduction over `livingCount` instead of using locked increments:

```
#if PARALLEL == 1
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static) num_threads(kernelsCount) \
                         reduction(+:livingCount)
#endif
for (int offsetI = 0; offsetI < n; offsetI += kernelPartSizeN)
{
  for (int offsetJ = 0; offsetJ < m; offsetJ += kernelPartSizeM)
  {
    int boundsN = min(kernelPartSizeN, n - offsetI), 
        boundsM = min(kernelPartSizeM, m - offsetJ);

    for (int kernelOffsetI = 0; kernelOffsetI < boundsN; ++kernelOffsetI)
    {
      for (int kernelOffsetJ = 0; kernelOffsetJ < boundsM; ++kernelOffsetJ)
      {
        if(BirthCell(offsetI + kernelOffsetI, offsetJ + kernelOffsetJ))
        {
          ++livingCount;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it some time earlier (see comments higher)

Comment: You should also change the loop schedule as noted. This will further reduce the OpenMP overhead and improve the compiler's options to optimize and possibly vectorise the code.

Comment: It has strong logic, but I have run it for about 20 times. `Static` version was 2.5% slower than `guided`

Comment: That makes little sense but then I'm not that familiar with the peculiarities of MS's OpenMP runtime.